# make command returns root folder instead of current folder in WSL2 when there is an include with SHELL

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run some basic makefile targets but it seems that make itself is returning the root folder `/` instead of the folder I am in. This causes all the files to be be not found as it tries to search them in root folder instead of the current folder even though `CURDIR` returns correctly.

I am on WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04, using GNU Make 4.2.1 with oh-my-zsh

Testing:

```
include Test.mk

wsl: ## Testing WSL make targets
    pwd
    echo "${CURDIR}"
```

Test.mk:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Output:

```
> make wsl
pwd
/
echo "/home/limonkufu/test-wsl"
/home/limonkufu/test-wsl
```

If you comment out the include or SHELL statement it works as expected (prints out `/home/limonkufu/test-wsl` as output of `pwd` as well)

Comment: How are you running `make`? Are you sure you are executing the correct `make`?

Comment: just running `make` and `which make` returns `/usr/bin/make` so I think it is the right one

Comment: What you have quoted cannot possibly be the output of the makefile you show here.  For one thing the commands themselves are not printed and make will always print the commands.  Please show the exact command you typed, the _full_ output you got (use cut and paste to be sure there are no typos), and the makefile you used and tell use the name of the makefile.

Comment: I had omitted the actual commands like you said and now amended that on my post, sorry.

Comment: If you type `pwd` at the shell prompt what does it say?  This seems like a wsl issue.

Comment: Hi, upon further investigation, somewhere in the makefile there was some `include` statements once I commented them out it worked. So shall I amend this or create a new question?

Comment: `make` certainly does not appear to be the issue.  At least, your test shows that it does not think that / is its working directory (which it exposes as `${CURDIR}`).  My guess is that the issue arises when it runs `bash` to execute commands.  Perhaps there's something weird with your WSL environment in that regard, such that `bash` starts with the root as its working directory, but on the other hand, perhaps there's something weird in your account's shell configuration files.

Comment: I have tried this with a fresh install of WSL and zsh (and oh-my-zsh) and the results are same but I agree it doesn't seem to be related to make specifically. 
Right now, I override any shell variable with `override SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh/`